# How to get all selected values from <select multiple=multiple>?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Seemed odd I couldn't find this one already asked, but here it goes!

I have an html  as follows:

```
<select id="select-meal-type" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="1">Breakfast</option>
    <option value="2">Lunch</option>
    <option value="3">Dinner</option>
    <option value="4">Snacks</option>
    <option value="5">Dessert</option>
</select>
```

How do I get all the values(an array?) that the user has selected in javascript?

For example, if the user has selected Lunch and Snacks, I want an array of { 2, 4 }.

This seems like it should be a very simple task but I can't seem to do it.

Thanks.