# Get selected options (onchange) from HTML to javascript array

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, arrays

I would like to get selected options to javascript, then create array with the option text.

This is what i did for now:

```js
 function selectMonthOnChange(month) {
    var selectedMonths = [];
    var selMonths = $('#sel_Months option:selected');
    
    $(selMonths).each(function(k) {
        selectedMonths.push(month.options[k].text);
    });
    console.log(selectedMonths);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select onchange="selectMonthOnChange(this)" id="sel_months" multiple="multiple ">
     <option value="1 ">Jan</option>
      <option value="2 ">Feb</option>
      <option value="3 ">Mar</option>
      ...
      <option value="12 ">Dec</option>
</select>
```

I want output (example, depends of selected months):

```
['Feb', 'May', 'Dec'];
```

I know, i'm doing something stupid and the answer is superb easy :) - gosh, I should take a break...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You did mistakes on closing each loop in jquery script
2. You did some mistakes on your select ID. id=""sel_months" and not id=""sel_months"
3. You console wrong variable.

This code will help you.

```
 function selectMonthOnChange(month)
{
      var selecetedMonths = [];
      var selMonths = $('#sel_months option:selected');
      $(selMonths).each(function(k)
      {
         selecetedMonths.push(month.options[k].text);   
      }); 
  console.log(selecetedMonths);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have quite a few issues here, such as mismatched variable names (`selecetedMonths` and `selectedMonths`), a typo in the jQuery selector `:seleceted`, missing closing parentheses in the Js, extra double quotes in the HTML and a general mish-mash of native and jQuery methods.

To simplify this and also improve the logic you should use unobtrusive event handlers instead of outdated `on*` event attributes. Then you can simply use `map()` to create an array of text of the selected options, like this:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#sel_months').change(function() {
    var arr = $(this).find('option:selected').map(function() {
      return $(this).text();
    }).get();

    console.log(arr);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="sel_months" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="1">Jan</option>
  <option value="2">Feb</option>
  <option value="3">Mar</option>
  <option value="4">Apr</option>
  <option value="5">May</option>
  <option value="6">Jun</option>
  <option value="7">Jul</option>
  <option value="8">Aug</option>
  <option value="9">Sep</option>
  <option value="10">Oct</option>
  <option value="11">Nov</option>
  <option value="12">Dec</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is also an issue in each closing tag and other variables issue too:

**DEMO:** https://codepen.io/creativedev/pen/VdMmYy

**HTML**

```
<select onchange="selectMonthOnChange(this)" id="sel_months" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="1">Jan</option>
    <option value="2">Feb</option>
    <option value="3">Mar</option>
    <option value="12">Dec</option>
</select>
```

**JS**

```
function selectMonthOnChange(month)
{
      var selecetedMonths = [];
      var selMonths = $('#sel_months option:selected');
//console.log(selMonths)
      $(selMonths).each(function(k)
      {
         selecetedMonths.push(month.options[k].text);   
      }); 
  console.log(selecetedMonths);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems you got some typos on your select ID. `id=""sel_months"` and not `id=""sel_months"` (one " is enought).

Also, you need to select the proper id, maybe you missed this one, or misstyped it (sel_months)

Here is a working solution, implemented there. [How to get all selected values from <select multiple=multiple>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11821261/how-to-get-all-selected-values-from-select-multiple-multiple)

```
let selectElement = document.getElementById('sel_months')
let selectedValues = Array.from(selectElement.selectedOptions)
    .map(option => option.value);
```

Answer (score -1):

You have some syntax and formatting problem. Other than that the code is working:

```
function selectMonthOnChange(month) {
  var selectedMonths = [];                              // misspelled `selected`
  var selMonths = $('#sel_months option:selected');     // misspelled `selected`

  selMonths.each(function(k) {
    selectedMonths.push(month.options[k].text);
  })                                                    // missing `)`
  console.log(selectedMonths);
}
```

Furthermore, there is a `"` you need to get rid of in the HTML:

```
<select onchange="selectMonthOnChange(this)" id="sel_months" multiple="multiple">
```

```js
function selectMonthOnChange(month) {
  var selectedMonths = [];
  var selMonths = $('#sel_months option:selected');

  selMonths.each(function(k) {
    selectedMonths.push(month.options[k].text);
  })
  console.log(selectedMonths);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select onchange="selectMonthOnChange(this)" id="sel_months" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="1">Jan</option>
  <option value="2">Feb</option>
  <option value="3">Mar</option>
  <option value="12">Dec</option>
</select>
```