# How to set values of multiple select using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, html-select

To set data of an `<input>` element using JavaScript, we assign the value and name of that element like this:

```
var form = document.createElement("form");
var element = document.createElement("input"); 
element.value=value;
element.name=name;
```

In the case of a `<select>` where the `multiple` attribute is present, how do I set the value of that select element? For instance, how would I set the value of the `myselect` element below:

```
<form method="post" action="/post/" name="myform">
  <select multiple name="myselect" id="myselect">
    <option value="1">option1</option>
    <option value="2">option2</option>
        ...
```

I tried to set the value by doing this `myselect.value=[1,2]` however it does not work. After selecting `option1` and `option2` I expected that it returns `[1,2]`, but it just returns "1".

Comment: Your question already have answers here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11821261/how-to-get-all-selected-values-from-select-multiple-multiple

Comment: Are you trying to select multiple items at the same time in your menu?

Comment: @YongQuan linked question doesn't sound related, I think eggandegg is asking how to *set* `<select>`, not *get* all options or the selected option.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To programmatically set multiple value options on a multi-select, you need to manually add `selected` attributes to the `<option>` elements that you want to select.

One approach to this is as follows:

```js
const select = document.getElementById('myselect')
const selectValues = [1, 2];

/* Iterate options of select element */
for (const option of document.querySelectorAll('#myselect option')) {

  /* Parse value to integer */
  const value = Number.parseInt(option.value);

  /* If option value contained in values, set selected attribute */
  if (selectValues.indexOf(value) !== -1) {
    option.setAttribute('selected', 'selected');
  }
  /* Otherwise ensure no selected attribute on option */
  else {
    option.removeAttribute('selected');
  }
}
```

```html
<select multiple name="myselect" id="myselect">
  <option value="1">option1</option>
  <option value="2">option2</option>
  <option value="3">option3</option>
  <option value="4">option4</option>
</select>
```

---

Comment: If you also want it to show as selected in the browser, make sure you also add `option.selected = true;`.

Answer (score 7):

It works

```js
var element = document.getElementById('selectMultiple');

// Set Values
var values = ["Gold", "Bronze"];
for (var i = 0; i < element.options.length; i++) {
    element.options[i].selected = values.indexOf(element.options[i].value) >= 0;
}

// Get Value
var selectedItens = Array.from(element.selectedOptions)
        .map(option => option.value)


spanSelectedItens.innerHTML = selectedItens
```

```html
<select name='selectMultiple' id="selectMultiple" multiple>
    <option value="Gold">Gold</option>
    <option value="Silver">Silver</option>
    <option value="Bronze">Bronze</option>
</select>
<br />
Selected: <span id="spanSelectedItens"></span>
```

Comment: Thanks for contributing! It would improve your answer to explain how your solution works.

Answer (score 4):

You can access the array of select options through the `options` property of the `select` object. Every option has a `selected` property that you can set.

```
document.myform.myselect.options[0].selected = true;
```

You can access the options by value using a query selector:

```
document.myform.myselect.querySelector("option[value="+value+"]")[0].selected = true;
```

Answer (score 1):

ES6 method to select `option1` and `option2`:

```js
const select = document.getElementById('myselect');

if (select) {
  Array.from(select.options).map((option) => {
    if (option.value === '1' || option.value === '2') {
      option.selected = true;
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<select multiple name="myselect" id="myselect">
  <option value="1">option1</option>
  <option value="2">option2</option>
  <option value="3">option3</option>
</select>
```

Note that we need to do `Array.from(select.options)` first to convert `select.options` into an array because `select.options` returns an HTMLOptionsCollection, which doesn't support the `map()` method.