# Javascript append input with "multiple" attribute

Tags: javascript, html, forms

How do I use javascript to append the value of an input when it has the attribute "multiple"?

i.e. `<input type='hidden' name='test[]' multiple>`

So like how you would set the value of a normal input `document.getElementById("myId").value = "whatever";` but to work with an input that has the attribute 'multiple'

Comment: I have no clue what you are asking. Your question needs more details. I assume it should be `type="file"`

Comment: Sorry, what? `multiple` is only valid for `<select>` or `<input type="file">`. And using Vanilla JS you can set/unset attributes assigning the value of the property directly `element.multiple=true|false`.

Comment: @Gabriel [`multiple` is valid for `input type="file"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file#multiple)

Comment: Multiple on an input only applies to file or email fields [MSDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#htmlattrdefmultiple). But like @Gabriel said you probably need `<select>`

Comment: Yes, sorry, my bad, I added it before you pointed it.

Comment: I am trying to set the value of the input, not the attribute. By set, I mean append because it is a 'multiple' input.

Comment: So, an `input type="hidden"` does not have the ability to set multiple values. So just set the `value` property of the `input` element. If you have actual code where you're trying that and it is failing, show us that code.

Comment: Setting multiple values of a `select` is covered in [How to set values of multiple select using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55486020/215552) however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am trying to set the value of the input, not the attribute. By set, I mean append because it is a 'multiple' input

The `multiple` attribute **does not** apply to `hidden` inputs.

If you want to append to the value, then read the current value, and include it in the new value.

```
input.value = input.value + "some other string";
```

Since you've used PHP-style naming conventions, possibly you want to create an additional input:

```
const newInput = document.createElement("input");
newInput.name = "test[]";
newInput.type = "hidden";
newInput.value = "some other string";
input.insertAdjacentElement("afterend", newInput);
```

So the submitted data will be treated as an array of values in whatever is processing it once submitted.

Comment: This was super helpful. Thanks :)

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
<select id="select">
    <option>...</option>
</select>

<script defer>
    document.querySelector("#select").setAttribute("multiple", "multiple")
</script>
```

Comment: I am trying to set the value of the input, and by set I mean append because it has the attribute 'multiple'. Sorry if the question was vague. I edited it to hopefully reflect this better