# HTML select multiple doesn't return an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I got an issue with some code I wrote in google script. I'm using a (select-multiple) and I want to return the **second** option that is selected. And append this option in a google sheet. I looked it up and tried different solutions but those don't seem to work.
This is the html:

```
  <select id ="multipleSelect" multiple="multiple">   
    <option value="1">Google Sheets </option>
    <option value="2">Excel </option>
    <option value="3">Word </option>
    <option value="4">Acess </option>
    <option value="5">Docs  </option>
    <option value="6">Pwp </option>
  </select>
```

This is the javascript:

```
<script>
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", doStuff);

function doStuff(){

    var userInfo = {};

    userInfo.firstName = document.getElementById("fn").value;
    userInfo.lastnName = document.getElementById("ln").value;
    userInfo.app = $('#multipleSelect').val()[1].value;

    google.script.run.userClicked(userInfo);

    document.getElementById("fn").value ="";
    document.getElementById("ln").value ="";

}
</script>
```

And this is where i write it to the google sheet:

```
function doGet(e) {

   return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("page").evaluate();
}

function userClicked(user){

    var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1L8QWNMDjoit8QILRCBYKply49FPjMVVRDyVhVET2fUA/edit#gid=0";

    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);

    var ws = ss.getSheetByName("Data");

    ws.appendRow([user.firstName, user.app, new Date()]);

}
function include(filename){
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename).getContent();

}
```

I'm able to write the first and last name of the user in the google sheet, but when implementing the multiple select, it won't do anything. Any tips are appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You're already using jQuery, why are you using `document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", doStuff);` instead of `$('#btn').click(doStuff)`? (and the same question for the code _in_ that function. If you already have jQuery anyway, no need for the super verbose DOM API?)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get all selected values from <select multiple=multiple>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11821261/how-to-get-all-selected-values-from-select-multiple-multiple)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    userInfo.app = $('#multipleSelect').val()[1].value;
```

should be

```
    userInfo.app = $('#multipleSelect').val()[1];
```

For a multi-select, `.val()` returns an array of the selected values, so `.val()[1]` is a string. `.value` is a property of input elements, not strings.

```js
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", doStuff);

function doStuff() {

  var userInfo = {};

  userInfo.app = $('#multipleSelect').val()[1];

  console.log(userInfo.app);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="multipleSelect" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="1">Google Sheets </option>
  <option value="2">Excel </option>
  <option value="3">Word </option>
  <option value="4">Acess </option>
  <option value="5">Docs </option>
  <option value="6">Pwp </option>
</select>

<button id="btn">Show second item</button>
```

You should probably also have code to check that they have selected at least 2 options.

Comment: Probably it is a good idea to also mention that `val()` in this case returns an array of selected values (which OP wants to get).

Comment: I thought it was obvious, but I reworded.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, i tried it first without the '.value' but that didn't work neither. I'm selecting more than one value every time i try the code (but i get your comment)

Comment: I've added a demo showing that it works. Select Excel and Word, and it should log `3`.

Comment: @Barmar, i solved it using the solution see below. thanks!

Comment: Assigning the value to a variable shouldn't make any difference.

Comment: @Barmar, your solution worked perfect as well, the issue was in the missing <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>, thanks for the reply

Comment: Except that you can check the length first. But if the length is at least 2, my code should work.

Answer (score 0):

Put the multi-select values into an array and then get the second index:

```js
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", doStuff);

function doStuff(){

    var userInfo = {};

    userInfo.firstName = "Bob";
    userInfo.lastnName = "Loblaw";
    let arr = $('#multipleSelect').val();
    userInfo.app = arr.length > 1 ? arr[1] : null
    console.clear()
    console.log(userInfo)

    //google.script.run.userClicked(userInfo);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id ="multipleSelect" multiple="multiple">   
    <option value="1">Google Sheets </option>
    <option value="2">Excel </option>
    <option value="3">Word </option>
    <option value="4">Acess </option>
    <option value="5">Docs  </option>
    <option value="6">Pwp </option>
  </select>
<input id="btn" type="button" value="do stuff" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You must call the `.val()` of `<select>` element itself to get the array of selected items.

```js
$(function() {
  function doStuff() {
    var userInfo = {
      firstName: $("#fn").val(),
      lastName: $("#ln").val(),
      app: $('#multipleSelect').val()
    };
    console.log(userInfo);
  }

  $("#btn").click(doStuff);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<strong>Name</strong><br /> Fisrt: <input id="fn" type="text" value="Thomas" /> Last: <input id="ln" type="text" value="Anderson" /><br />
<select id="multipleSelect" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="1">Google Sheets </option>
  <option value="2">Excel </option>
  <option value="3">Word </option>
  <option value="4">Acess </option>
  <option value="5">Docs </option>
  <option value="6">Pwp </option>
</select><br />
<button id="btn">Go</button>
```

> When the first element in the collection is a select-multiple (i.e., a select element with the multiple attribute set), `.val()` returns an array containing the value of each selected option. As of **jQuery 3.0**, if no options are selected, it returns an empty array (`[]`); prior to **jQuery 3.0**, it returns `null`.

See More: https://api.jquery.com/val/

This of course requires jQuery to be loaded. With your use of Google API, I would advise jQuery 3.0 or higher.