# How to return the values of selected options using JS filter function

Tags: javascript, ecma

I would like to get a an array returned of the values of the selected option.
I would like to use Array.prototype.filter.

I can get the filter to return an array of selected options but not an array of the value of the options. Is there a method to return an array of the value of the selected options.

I can get an array of the values using forEach or a for loop but not the filter function. If this is not possible I would like to know the reason.

Select with the values

```
<select
                multiple
                className="form-control"
                id="genre"
                onChange={handleGenreChnage}>
                <option>drama</option>
                <option>music</option>
                <option>adventure</option>
                <option>historical</option>
                <option>action</option>
</select>
```

Function using filter - returns option not the value from option.

```
const handleGenreChnage = (event) => {
    const { options } = event.target;
    
    const optionsArray = [...options];

    const values  = optionsArray.forEach((option) => {
    
        if (option.selected) {
            return option.value;
            
        }
    });
    
    setForm({ ...form, genre: values.toString() });
};
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get all selected values from <select multiple=multiple>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11821261/how-to-get-all-selected-values-from-select-multiple-multiple)

Comment: Especially this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54578977/4403732

Comment: You want `filter` and `map` instead of `forEach` with a conditional. And yes, it's not possible to do this using only `filter`.

Comment: `filter()` is just an in-or-out method, it doesn't affect the values themselves. If you're looking for a single call, you could do it with the `reduce()` method, where you'd decide which elements to include and translate options to their values.

Comment: Many thanks - @RoboRobok stackoverflow.com/a/54578977/4403732  is what I was looking for!!