# How to transfer selected values from select element to javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu

i have a `select` element with multiple selection, like this:

```
<select multiple>
  <option value="en">English</option>
  <option value="de">German</option>
</select>
```

And i have a javascript, which should use selected values, looking like:

```
$.ajax({
                url: window.location.protocol + "//example.com/search",
                jsonp: "jsonp",
                dataType: "jsonp",
                data: {
                q: querykeyword,
                client: "chrome",
                hl: "HERE SHOULD APPEAR ONE OR TWO SELECTED VALUES"
                }
```

So the last code line should look like `hl: "en"` or, `hl: "de"`, or `hl: ["en","de"]`.

How can i transfer values from `select` element into javascript?

Comment: `document.querySelector("select").value`

Comment: It would make your backend less complicated if you sent `hl: ["en"]` and consistently sent an array

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get all selected values from <select multiple=multiple>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11821261/how-to-get-all-selected-values-from-select-multiple-multiple)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to take the selected value from the select element. You can do that by: `document.querySelector("select").value`, so the full solution for your code will be:

```
$.ajax({
      url: window.location.protocol + "//example.com/search",
      jsonp: "jsonp",
      dataType: "jsonp",
      data: {
        q: querykeyword,
        client: "chrome",
        hl: document.querySelector("select").value
      });
```

Comment: A dump of code is rarely a great answer. Code, properly formatted, along with an explanation of the code and why/how it works is much more often upvoted (on questions which are not common duplicates).

Comment: .value will show only one selected option. refer to my answer about the example.

Comment: Or, refer to ***the answers to the duplicate question***.

Comment: @Evgeniy does it work properly when you selected both?

Comment: @WilliamWang maybe the `multiple` attribute is there by mistake.

Comment: no it's correct. according to his question description, he need `hl: ["en","de"]`

Comment: @WilliamWang yes. I can't answer the question with 100% guarantee - i query Google Suggest, and what i realized, that there are results from both languages. Yes, both langages are not mistake, i'm indeed need both.

Comment: @Evgeniy so, document.querySelector("select").value will return ["en", "de"] when you select both? can you refer to below answer about this?

Comment: yes, you are right :( its only one value here

Comment: refer to below answer to get all selected values which uses selectedOptions. @Evgeniy

Comment: @Evgeniy in that case, go to William Wang answer.

Answer (score 2):

Use `selectedOptions` property.

```
var selectedOptions = document.querySelector("select").selectedOptions;
var values = [];
for (let i=0; i<selectedOptions.length; i++) {
  values.push(selectedOptions[i].value);
}
```

---

`.value` will not work, as it will show only one selected option.

```js
console.log(document.querySelector("select").value)
```

```html
<select multiple>
  <option value="volvo" selected>Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab" selected>Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Comment: You just need to get the `.value` of the select. Also, instead of deleting an answer and then posting a new one, you can just edit your deleted answer and then undelete it.

Comment: .value() will return the only one value when you select multiple options.

Comment: as per OP, there is no dropdown mention, https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_select_multiple.asp

Comment: This question has been asked and answered many times before. There is no reason to answer it again.

Comment: @OrAssayag In the OP: `<select multiple>`, which means the user can select multiple options.

Comment: @HereticMonkey, yep, my bad. still, `.value` will do the trick

Comment: @OrAssayag, I have updated answer, as .value will show only one selected option.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I have updated answer, as .value will show only one selected option.

Comment: On trying to implement it i get `selectedOptions.map is not a function`. How should i get the value from `var values` to `hl: "..."`?