# JS return values from multi select

Tags: javascript, asp-classic, multi-select

Using Classic ASP and JS.
How do I return multiple values from a multi select? The code below is only returning the first value selected.

in my .asp code

```
<select name="month_day" multiple="multiple" size="5" id="month_day_select">

onClick="document.useredit.schedule_details.value=getDetailValue();
```

in my .js code

```
function getDetailValue() {
var sel_index=document.useredit.month_day.selectedIndex;
s_detail=document.useredit_monthday.options[sel_index].value;

return s_detail;
}
```

Comment: Why JS, why not just `Split(Request("month_day"), ",")` and loop through the data used to build the dropdown and compare the values setting `selected` if they match?

Comment: I'm modifying an old program to allow multiple values selected. The code goes through the js to do some other stuff aswell, so I don't want to mess with it too much. I need to be able to read the values selected in the .js

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get all selected values from <select multiple=multiple>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11821261/how-to-get-all-selected-values-from-select-multiple-multiple)

Comment: You need to pass the request.form object yourself because there will be multiple variables with the same name. 

Your variable of month_day will be in the request.form variable as:

month_day=01&month_day=02&otherdata=value&somethingelse=something .... etc..

For example, from above if you have selected month_day twice it will have the variable twice. This is a normal HTTP response, it is that classic ASP doesn't offer up an array or anything like that for form values with the same name.